# Modify sessionState mode from "InProc" to "SQLServer"

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012, .net-3.5

We are looking to change the **SessionMode** in our application from *Inrpoc* to *SQLServer*. In our config file we have

```
<connectionStrings>
    <!-- !!! The connection-string to the database used by the application tier -->
    <add name="serverRepository" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="server=serverName;database=databaseName;uid=uid;pwd=password"/>
</connectionStrings>

<system.web>
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20"/>
</system.web>
```

I am following [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx#Anchor_1) link to understand and apply the changes. But here the connection string is defined in the SessionState tag only. 
Is it compulsory ??

Also what other things I should keep in mind to make this transition.

Comment: Depends on your requirements, i generally use Stateserver, it runs as a service on the web server. In Proc should provide the better performance. But depending on what you are using sessions id's for in your app. In the past I have just changed it in IIS and haven't had to touch the web config.

Comment: You can reference the connectionString entry in the sessionState. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you can set it to the name "serverRepository" if you want. You need to run Aspnet_regsql.exe and give it the proper permissions. There are a lot of things to consider, it will be slower than InProc and everything must be serializable. If you are running a web farm, you need to specify a machine key in your web config  that is the same on all servers.